# Why saying $exception {"Incorrect syntax near ','."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

> Incorrect syntax near ',' exception arises when application is set to run.

In SQL Server Management Studio query is running fine. But it throws an exception while application is set to run.

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[ USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS]
    @MONTH INT = 4,
    @YEAR INT = 2017
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  
        P.PbsName, PC.CauseName,
        dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(PCI.DayFrom) + N'/' + dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(PCI.MonthFrom) + N'/' +
                dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(PCI.YearFrom) + N'থেকে' + dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(PCI.DayTo) + N'/' +
                dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(PCI.MonthTo) + N'/' + dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(PCI.YearTo) 'Date',
        PCI.Remarks
    FROM    
        Pbs P
    INNER JOIN 
        ProbableConnectionInfo PCI ON PCI.PbsId = P.PbsId
    INNER JOIN 
        ConnectionPendingCause CPC ON PCI.Id = CPC.ProbableConnectionId
    INNER JOIN 
        PendingCause PC ON CPC.PendingCauseId = PC.Id
    WHERE   
        PCI.MONTH = @MONTH AND
        YEAR = @YEAR AND
        CPC.PendingNumber > 0;

    SELECT  
        dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(SUM(IC.Pending)) 'PendingApplication',
        dbo.F_CONVERT_ENG_NUMBER_TO_BNG(SUM(IC.loadNeed)) 'AppliedLoadAmount'
    FROM    
        IndustrialConnection IC
    INNER JOIN 
        ProbableConnectionInfo PCI ON IC.ProbableConnectionId = PCI.Id
    WHERE   
        PCI.MONTH = @MONTH AND YEAR = @YEAR
    GROUP BY 
        PCI.PbsId;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

and here is where the problem is showing up:

```
public static DataTable GetDataByStoredProcedure(string spName, List<SqlParameter> pars = null)
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if (pars != null)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(pars.ToArray());
    }

    var dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    var dt = new DataTable("Command");
    dt.Load(dataReader);

    //sqlConnection.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Here is where I am using the procedure:

```
public void ShowPendingIndustrialInfo(string exportType, int year, int month)
{
    List<SqlParameter> pars = new List<SqlParameter>();

    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@month", SqlDbType.Int);
    p1.Value = month;

    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@year", SqlDbType.Int);
    p2.Value = year;

    pars.Add(p1);
    pars.Add(p2);

    var data = SPService.GetDataByStoredProcedure("USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS",pars);
    ReportHelper.ShowReport(data, exportType, "rptPendingDetails.rpt");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you build an SqlCommand to run a stored procedure you need to set the CommandType property to CommandType.StoredProcedure, otherwise, the default for this property is Text and the engine tries to parse your command name like if was a literal sql command. Of course the name *month_wise_pending_details* is not a valid sql command text.

```
  var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConnection);
  sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  var dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

I should also warn you about a problem in your code. You have a global connection object and you don't dispose it after using it. This is a bad practice because the ADO.NET implements [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) with great efficiency removing the need to keep these kind of object always open

```
public class SPService
{
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;

    public static DataTable GetDataByStoredProcedure(string spName)
    {
        using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using(SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using(SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var dt = new DataTable("Command");
                dt.Load(dataReader);
                return dt;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to pass parameters to your stored procedure then you need some changes to your code:

The method should receive a `List<SqlParameter>` as a second argument, this list is added to the SqlCommand.Parameters collection

```
public static DataTable GetDataByStoredProcedure(string spName, List<SqlParameter> pars = null)
{
    using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if(pars != null) sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(pars.ToArray());
        using(SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var dt = new DataTable("Command");
            dt.Load(dataReader);
            return dt;
         }
    }
}
```

And the calling code changes to pass these parameters

```
public void ShowPendingIndustrialInfo(string exportType, int year, int month)
{
    List<SqlParameter> pars = new List<SqlParameter>();
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@month", SqlDbType.Int);
    p1.Value = month;
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@year", SqlDbType.Int);
    p2.Value = year;
    pars.Add(p1);
    pars.Add(p2);
    var data = SPService.GetDataByStoredProcedure("USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS", pars);
    ReportHelper.ShowReport(data, exportType, "rptPendingDetails.rpt");
}
```

**FINAL EDIT**
About the error the stored procedure not found: If you look carefully to the ALTER statement you will notice a space before the name of the procedure. This is the reason of the persinstence of the error also after all those previous fixing

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[ USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS]
                     ^
```

Comment: I have noticed that you have changed the name of sp. Now it reads as *USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS*. Which is the correct one? Can you check with the debugger what is the value of the parameter passed to your method?

Comment: parameter passed to the method as "USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS4,2017" (month,year) which is correct i think. but the procedure not found. @Steve

Comment: If your stored procedure is named USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS but you pass USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS,4,2017 then no wonder if the database cannot find that name

Comment: <connectionStrings><add name="Connection"connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-BVVG334\SERVERSAJID;Database=PBSM; User id=;Password=;Integrated Security=false;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: The problem is in the name of the SP. you added the month and the year but this makes the name inexistant. I have added code to show you how to pass the parameters (@mont and @year) optionally required by the SP.

Comment: the procedure accepts two parameter month and year.@ Steve

Comment: This is what I have done in the final edit. I build a List containing two parameters and pass it to the SqlCommand.Parameters collection. Then I call the SP with its exact name (no pending month,year as literal string)

Comment: edited as u suggest but Add can not have two parameters...can not resolve Value.. I tried to call without parameter only by the SP Name, it's time it also shows could not find SP

Comment: Please refresh the answer. There was an error that is now fixed

Comment: Do you really have a space before the name _[ USP_GET_MONTH_WISE_PENDING_DETAILS]_ ?

Answer (score 0):

ru,

add the following command in your code notifying c# that the sqlcommand is a stored procedure.

```
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

IE:

```
namespace PBSM.DBGateway
{
public class SPService
{
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
    private static SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    public static DataTable GetDataByStoredProcedure(string spName)
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConnection);
        **sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;**
        var dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        var dt = new DataTable("Command");
        dt.Load(dataReader);
        sqlConnection.Close();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

}

Kindly mark my reply as the answer if it helped you. Regards.